# SQL Server count distinct for each record

Tags: sql-server, windows, count

I have table in SQL Server 2016 with 6 columns of numbers and a 7th column (`numCount`) that needs to be the number of unique values across the 6 values (within each record).

Like this:

| Num1 | Num2 | Num3 | Num4 | Num5 | Num6 | numCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 11 | 10 | 12 | 10 | 11 | 3 |
| 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

This just throws an error:

```
UPDATE Table 
SET numCount = COUNT(*) 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Num5, Num6)
```

Is there a way to update `numCount` for each record to be the distinct # of values across the 6 values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this slightly shorter than the accepted answer, in a similar fashion to your existing query:

```sql
UPDATE t
SET numCount =
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT N) 
    FROM
        (VALUES (Num1),(Num2),(Num3),(Num4),(Num5),(Num6)) v(N) )
FROM Table t;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `CROSS APPLY` in concert with a `CTE`

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
Select *
  From YourTable A
  Cross Apply ( Select cnt=count(Distinct value) 
                  From (values  (num1)
                               ,(num2)
                               ,(num3)
                               ,(num4)
                               ,(num5)
                               ,(num6)
                       )v(Value)
              )B
)
Update cte set numCount=cnt
```

**The Updated Table**

```
Num1    Num2    Num3    Num4    Num5    Num6    numCount
10      11      10      12      10      11      3
10      10      10      10      10      10      1
```